# Powershell running under a service hangs on *.zip CopyHere

Tags: powershell, hudson

I'm running a Windows Service (Hudson) which in turn spawns a PowerShell process to run my custom PowerShell commands.  Part of my script is to unzip a file using CopyHere.  When I run this script locally, I see a progress dialog pop up as the files are extracted and copied.  However, when this runs under the service, it hangs at the point where a dialog would otherwise appear.

Here's the unzip portion of my script.

```
# Extract the contents of a zip file to a folder
function Extract-Zip {
    param([string]$zipFilePath, [string]$destination)
    if(test-path($zipFilePath))     {   
        $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application

        $zipFile = get-item $zipFilePath
        $zipFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipFile.fullname)

        $destinationFile = get-item $destination
        $destinationFolder = $shellApplication.NameSpace($destinationFile.fullname)

        $destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipFolder.Items())
    }
}
```

I suspect that because its running under a service process which is headless (no interaction with the desktop), its somehow stuck trying to display a dialog.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you try the powershell plugin for Hudson? May be that will help.

Answer (score 3):

If it's still actual, I managed to fix this with having CopyHere params equal 1564.

So in my case extract zip function looks like:

```
    function Expand-ZIPFile{
    param(
    $file, $destination
    )
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
    $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item,1564)
    "$($item.path) extracted"
    }
```

1564 description can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx:

(4) Do not display a progress dialog box.
(8) Give the file being operated on a new name in a move, copy, or rename operation if a file with the target name already exists.
(16) Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed.
(512) Do not confirm the creation of a new directory if the operation requires one to be created.
(1024) Do not display a user interface if an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If this is running on Vista or Windows 7, popping up UI from a service isn't going to be seen by the end user as you suspected. See this paper on [Session 0 Isolation](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysinternals/Session0Changes.mspx).  However, does the progress dialog require user input?  If not, I wouldn't think that would cause the service to hang.  I would look for an option to disable the progress display.  If you can't find that, then try switching to another ZIP extractor.  [PSCX 1.2](http://pscx.codeplex.com) comes with an Expand-Archive cmdlet.  I'm sure there are also others available.

Comment: The progress dialog shoudl not be requiring user input.  When I run it from a command prompt, it doesn't -- it just shows the progress dialog without any required input, and then when its done the dialog disappears.

The actual progress dialog is spawned by the CopyHere method.  Supposedly, there are options you should be able to pass to block any potential interaction, but there's dozens of posts out there complaining that PowerShell ignores those particular options.

I had hoped to avoid 3rd-party stuff as much as possible, but I may have to cave.

Comment: PSCX providers wrapper cmdlets on top of 7-Zip but if you want, you can always use 7-Zip directly - http://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315276.aspx) for PowerShell, it looks like the **-NonInteractive** option may help here

Comment: That would prevent PowerShell from displaying a prompt but I don't think it would prevent the Windows shell from displaying UI.